# Having trouble using git push

Tags: git, github

I am new to code and have been trying to push a text file to my repo on GitHub but I keep on getting the same error.

When I use git push I get the following error:

```
    $ git push
    fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
    To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Then I do git push --set-upstream origin master and get this response:

```
    $ git push --set-upstream origin master
    To https://github.com/KMagrane/test-repo.git
    ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/KMagrane/test-
    repo.git'
    hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is 
    behind
    hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
    hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
    hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for 
    details.
```

So I tried git pull origin master and get this response:

```
    $ git pull origin master
    From https://github.com/KMagrane/test-repo
    * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
    fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

So I am not sure what else  to try to push the file to my repo. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you end up on your current `master` branch?  Did you clone the remote repository?

Comment: I did clone the remote repository

Comment: Your errors imply that Git does not recognize the remote repo as having anything to do with your local repo.  There might be a way to save this, but I might just clone again.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are working on a local repository which has nothing to do with the remote `master` branch or its repository.  Rather than trying to salvage your current setup, I would recommend cloning your remote repository into a new folder somewhere:

```
git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

Then, checkout the `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
```

Finally, copy your text file where you want it, do `git add` followed by `git commit`, and then push:

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use this command in git bash where your git repo is cloned.

```
git status
```

Then, if you have un-merged files please add them using

```
git add .
```

then commit it using

```
git commit -m "<comment to push>"
```

then use

```
 git push origin <branch-name>
```

if you are still getting any errors please post it back.